# Loading data in a dataframe - pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, azure-synapse

I'm trying to load data into a dataframe from a partitionned structure.
I have a specific period selected in my example and then loop to have my data range.
But This is not very performant!

```
start_date = inputdate

end_date = inputend

df_union = None

for single_date in pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='D'):
    yy = single_date.strftime("%y")
    mm = single_date.strftime("%m")
    dd = single_date.strftime("%d")

    df = spark.read.parquet(f"abfs://XXXXX.dfs.core.windows.net/coredb/user_action/{yy}/{mm}/{dd}/user_action.parquet") \
                    .select("user_action_id", "account_id", "inserted" , "partner_id", "status", "service_id") 
            
            
    if df_union is None:
        df_union = df
    else:
        df_union = df_union.unionAll(df)
```

Any help ? :)

Comment: Is your folder structure have any other folders apart from the data wise partitioned folders?

Comment: Hi, no. It is only based on the date formated as 23/01/01

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use wildcard paths to read all files (with same schema) directly.

- I have a file called `sample1.csv` (3 rows) in my source directories structured as `yyyy/MM/dd`. I have 3 date folder structures i.e., `2023/02/25, 2023/02/26 and 2023/02/27`. Using the following code I am able to read the data successfully:

```
df = spark.read.option("header",True).csv('abfss://data@datalk2702.dfs.core.windows.net/2023/*/*/sample1.csv')

display(df.limit(10))
```

[image]

- But this reads all files with name `sample1.csv` from everything inside `2023 folder`. If you want to read only in between `startdate and enddate`, use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
start_date = '2023-02-25'
end_date = '2023-02-27'

base_path = 'abfss://data@datalk2702.dfs.core.windows.net/'
paths = []  

for single_date in pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='D'):

    paths.append(base_path + f'{single_date.strftime("%Y")}/{single_date.strftime("%m")}/{single_date.strftime("%d")}/sample1.csv')

#print(paths)

df = spark.read.option("header",True).csv(paths)
display(df.limit(10))
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you for your reply! This should work, but in my example, not all partitions might exist. In that case I get the error that the folder was not found. 

I cannot seem to find a decent way to bypass this! How could I still get the result for the ones that did not throw that error?

Comment: One thing that you can do is get the list of folders using `dbutils.fs.ls`. Then filter out the `paths` array using the return value of `dbutils.fs.ls` (remove paths which are not present)

Comment: Would you have a more exact example on this? :/
The date ranges I would be using could go up to 1 year - 1 day. Would this mean having to loop every single day to check if it exists,  ahead of getting the files?